# Tick Identification

Tags: species-identification

While enjoying the outdoors in mid-Missouri and Northern Iowa, I came across this tick in my belongings. I can't distinguish whether it is a dog tick, a rocky mountain tick or some other species.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tick you found is a female American dog tick (Dermacentor variabilis) and not a lone-star tick (Amblyomma americanum). Female lone-star ticks do not have white coloration towards the head and only a round dot in the middle of their body. The following PDF document offers a visual comparison of the two species:

https://store.extension.iastate.edu/Product/pm2036-pdf